# MongoDB: Does anyone know why I can't insert/save documents?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Here is my class:

```
class MongoDBHelper
{
    public MongoDBHelper()
    {
            mClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://" + MongoDBAddress);
            mServer = mClient.GetServer();
            mBadassDatabase = mServer.GetDatabase("mydb");
    }

    public void InsertEvent(string eventName, List<BsonDocument> data)
    {
        if (data.Count <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var ts = EpochTimestamp;
        foreach (var i in data)
        {
            i.Add("server_name", OnlineSettings.Instance.ServerName);
            i.Add("ts", ts);
        }

        var collection = mBadassDatabase.GetCollection(eventName);
        collection.InsertBatch(data);
    }

    private MongoClient mClient;
    private MongoServer mServer;
    private MongoDatabase mBadassDatabase;
}
```

When I call InsertEvent() nothing gets added to the database.  There are no errors or exceptions of any kind.  It seems to work except when I check the database the new documents aren't there.

I've tried changing the code to iterate over the array and call Insert() or Save() instead of InsertBatch() but still nothing gets added to my database.

I know I'm connected to the right collection because I can call FindOne() and retrieve the documents that are already there.

Can anyone see anything I am doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I interrogated the return value from InsertBatch().  There are no errors returned, but the DocumentsAffected property is 0.

Comment: Which MongoDb version are you using?

Comment: I figured it out.  It turns out the machine I was testing on was running 2 instances of MongoDB.  The remote code was writing to one database and the local code was reading from another.